# python-iptables Code Not Working

Tags: python, oop, iptables

So I'm new to Python and have been playing around with the python-iptables library. I wrote the following simple class (or what I think is a class) and I can't get it working. As is it simply doesn't do anything to the iptables rules. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you in advance.

```
class Table(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.chain = None
            self.rule = None
            self.match = None
            self.setTarget = ""
            self.rule = ""
            self.insert = ""
            self.target = ""

        def setInput(self):
            self.chain = "iptc.Chain(iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER), 'INPUT')"

        def setOutput(self):
            self.chain = "iptc.Chain(iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER), 'OUTPUT')"

        def setTarg(self, target):
            self.setTarget = "rule.target = iptc.Target(rule, " + target + ")"

        def createRule(self):
            self.rule = "iptc.Rule()"

        def insertRule(self):
            self.insert = "chain.insert_rule(rule)"

    table = Table()
    table.createRule()
    table.setInput()
    table.setTarg('DROP')
    table.insertRule()
```

I know this may be ugly but it's my first attempt at creating a class so cut me some slack please :)

~

Comment: You really really have to read the documentation: https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables/blob/master/doc/examples.rst

Comment: ``setTarg`` definition is definitely wrong - you should be using ``target`` on the right hand side to capture the input, instead of ``self.target``

Comment: I know I'm having issues here, I think I fixed the one you referred to Michel-slm. I have a mental block when it comes to OOP. I have this working in a functional design which I've posted to this site. I'm having serious issues with doing it OOP style.